# How to caculate the size of input weight matrix when using the cell data in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, network-programming, non-linear-regression

How to caculate the size of input weight matrix when using the cell data to train a neural network in MATLAB?

Hello everyone,

recently I am learning to use NARX for time series modeling and forecasting. Now I have doubts about the number of input weights for training the neural network with cell arrays.

By reading previous questions, I successfully used multiple sets of time series to train a single model, that is, using cell structure data. The problem URL is [here](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/matlabcentral/answers/346785-is-it-possible-to-train-a-narx-model-using-multiple-data-sets-from-the-same-time-series#answer_412366).

Simply put, for an ***N***-input-single-output model, if I want to use ***M*** sets of input data with different time series lengths (up to ***T*** time units) for training, you can build a 1 × ***T*** cell array, in each cell Contains an ***N*** × ***M*** double array. Use NaN to fill data gaps due to different time series lengths.

Taking my work as an example, it contains 4 inputs and 1 output. I selected 10 sets of data to build a training set, and the longest time length is 482. So the size of my cell array is 1 × 482, and each cell is a 4 × 10 double array.

Set the hidden layer of NARX to 1, the number of neurons to 10, and the time delay to 2.

```
clc;clear;close all; 
load('E:\\Engine\\up_N1pre.mat') 

X = Input_train; % 1 × 482 cell, each cell is 4 × 10 double 
T = N1_train;    % 1 × 482 cell, each cell is 1 × 10 double 

trainFcn = 'trainlm'; 
inputDelays = 1:2; 
feedbackDelays = 1:2; 
hiddenLayerSize = 10; 

net = narxnet(inputDelays,feedbackDelays,hiddenLayerSize,'open',trainFcn); 

[x,xi,ai,t] = preparets(net,X,{},T); 
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100; 
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100; 
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100; 

% Train the Network 
[net,tr] = train(net,x,t,xi,ai);
```

After successfully training the open-loop NARX network, I checked the input weights using net.IW. The structure is as follows:

```
2×2 cell array
{10×8 double} {10×2 double}
{ 0×0 double} { 0×0 double}
```

I can understand that net.IW{1,1} is related to input, and net.IW{1,2} is related to exogenous input. In terms of generalization, I think that if the time delay is modified to ***K*** for training in this example, the size of net.IW obtained after training is as follows:

```
2×2 cell array
{10×4×K double} {10×K double}
{ 0×0 double} { 0×0 double}
```

For comparison, I used the BP neural network to perform network training on the same input training set, setting 1 hidden layer and 10 neurons:

```
clc;clear;close all;
load('E:\\Engine\\up_N1pre.mat')

x_train_data=Input_train; % 1 × 482 cell, each cell is 4 × 10 double
y_train_data=N1_train;    % 1 × 482 cell, each cell is 1 × 10 double

net=newff(x_train_data,y_train_data,10,{'tansig','purelin'});

[net,~]=train(net,x_train_data,y_train_data);
```

The resulting net.IW structure is as follows:

```
2×1 cell array
{10×8 double}
{0×0 double}
```

I am very confused here, why is net.IW{1,1} not a 10×4 double array? Is it because of the special impact of the cell array as a training set.I assume that the connection structure between network input and hidden layers is shown in the following figure：
[connection structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYSD8.png)

To sum up, I have two main questions:

1. Is the number of input weights for NARX network training the same as I think?
2. Why is the size of the input weight matrix doubled when training the BP network?

Thanks in advance!